# Spinning up mongo db on Amazon Fargate

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We are trying to setup microservice architecture on Amazon ECS using Fargate. When it comes to database, we are not able to spin up instance of mongodb. The database automatically switches off after 3 minutes.

The log states
`{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-15T15:34:17.913+00:00"},"s":"I", "c":"REPL", "id":4784900, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}`

My question is ,

a) What could be the possible reason of auto shutdown of the db after 3 minutes?

b) Is this the right approach to spin up database in Amazon fargate ? Or is there a better way to achieve the same ?

Comment: Paste complete server log into question (or link to it if too large).

Comment: @D.SM There is no specific failure log. This comes after 2 minutes and it shuts down. Do you want to have a look at the whole startup to shutdown log?

Comment: Well, what does "complete server log" mean to you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain about the core MongoDB issue. My first guess would be a failing or misconfigured health check on ECS; if this were the case, the health check would appear in your ECS event history (in the (new) UI: Cluster > Select the service > Notifications at the bottom).

If there are no bad health check notifications, then that would rule this out, and more information may be necessary to fully diagnose, such as the full ECS/Fargate Service/Task configuration.

Generally, and more to your second question, running databases on Fargate is not a recommended use-case. Fargate is a better fit for stateless services, like web APIs, which are more tolerant to being stopped and started frequently, and receiving different IP addresses upon each start. Within AWS, MongoDB would be a better fit on simple EC2, or via their [DocumentDB](https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/) MongoDB-like managed service. There are also several MongoDB managed hosting providers which can provide the low-management, serverless feel of Fargate, like [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas).